# Spring boot transaction hanging if two transactions are updating the same row

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I'm trying to update the same row in two separate transactions that I'm managing programmatically.

Here is the test:

```java
    @Sql("classpath:sql/balance/account_with_balance_EE.sql")
    @Test
    void changeNoLock() {
        long balanceId = 10000L;
        DefaultTransactionDefinition firstTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        DefaultTransactionDefinition secondTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        firstTransactionDefinition.setName("firstTransaction");
        secondTransactionDefinition.setName("secondTransaction");
        firstTransactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        secondTransactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

        TransactionStatus firstTransactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(firstTransactionDefinition);
        balanceService.change(balanceId, BigDecimal.ONE);

        TransactionStatus secondTransactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(secondTransactionDefinition);
        balanceService.change(balanceId, BigDecimal.ONE);

        txManager.commit(firstTransactionStatus);
        txManager.commit(secondTransactionStatus);


        BalanceDto balanceDto = balanceService.find(balanceId);

        assertEquals(new BigDecimal("2.00"), balanceDto.getBalanceAmount());
    }
```

balanceService#change method is transactional with default propagation and default isolation.

When I run this test it's just hanging, the only time it doesn't hang is when I commit first transaction before starting the second why. Why is this happening?

I'm using Java 17 with Spring boot 3 and a Postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have deadlocks, you could create a retry mechanism to handle deadlock situations, and catch deadlock exceptions and retry the transactions after a delay

```
import org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException;

@Test
void changeWithRetry() {
    long balanceId = 10000L;
    DefaultTransactionDefinition firstTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    DefaultTransactionDefinition secondTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    firstTransactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    secondTransactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

    int maxAttempts = 3;

    BiConsumer<DefaultTransactionDefinition, String> retryLogic = (transactionDefinition, name) -> {
        int attempt = 0;
        while (attempt < maxAttempts) {
            TransactionStatus transactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
            try {
                balanceService.change(balanceId, BigDecimal.ONE);
                txManager.commit(transactionStatus);
                break;
            } catch (DeadlockLoserDataAccessException e) {
                txManager.rollback(transactionStatus);
                attempt++;
                if (attempt >= maxAttempts) {
                    throw e;
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    retryLogic.accept(firstTransactionDefinition, "firstTransaction");
    retryLogic.accept(secondTransactionDefinition, "secondTransaction");

    BalanceDto balanceDto = balanceService.find(balanceId);
    assertEquals(new BigDecimal("2.00"), balanceDto.getBalanceAmount());
}
```

Or a simplified and with best performance version

```
@Test
void changeWithoutRetry() {
    long balanceId = 10000L;
    DefaultTransactionDefinition firstTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    DefaultTransactionDefinition secondTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    firstTransactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    secondTransactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

    TransactionStatus firstTransactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(firstTransactionDefinition);
    balanceService.change(balanceId, BigDecimal.ONE);
    txManager.commit(firstTransactionStatus);

    TransactionStatus secondTransactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(secondTransactionDefinition);
    balanceService.change(balanceId, BigDecimal.ONE);
    txManager.commit(secondTransactionStatus);

    BalanceDto balanceDto = balanceService.find(balanceId);
    assertEquals(new BigDecimal("2.00"), balanceDto.getBalanceAmount());
}
```